# Setting AssemblyAttribute in .csproj file with enum value

Tags: .net, .net-5, csproj, assembly-attributes

I want to set an AssemblyAttribute with an enum parameter in the .csproj file.
How do I achieve that?

I am aware that I can set it the following way within a file:

```
[assembly: TestDataSourceDiscovery(TestDataSourceDiscoveryOption.DuringExecution)]
```

However, I want to distribute this via NuGet (in build/MyPackage.props) and hence want to declare it there the following way (as most people do it with InternalsVisible):

```
<AssemblyAttribute Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestDataSourceDiscoveryAttribute">
  <_Parameter1>Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestDataSourceDiscoveryOption.DuringExecution</_Parameter1>
</AssemblyAttribute>
```

I do get the error CS1503 stating

> Argument 1: cannot convert from 'string' to 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestDataSourceDiscoveryOption'

How can I provide the parameter value as TestDataSourceDiscoveryOption enum?

Answer (score 3):

I finally found what I was looking for after digging though GitHub Issue for quite some time:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <AssemblyAttribute Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestDataSourceDiscovery" >
    <_Parameter1>Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting.TestDataSourceDiscoveryOption.DuringExecution</_Parameter1>
    <_Parameter1_IsLiteral>true</_Parameter1_IsLiteral>
  </AssemblyAttribute>
</ItemGroup>
```

For the interested, the solution to the requested feature after a long discussion: [Add support for non-string assembly attributes#2281](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/issues/2281#issuecomment-803217731)

Corresponding PR: [Allow parameter type name to be specified for WriteCodeFragment task #6285](https://github.com/dotnet/msbuild/pull/6285)